# Deconstructing 2D array in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to destructure a 2D array in Google Apps Script and it remains unchanged.

I found a link that explains how to destructure an array in google apps script similar to the syntax for javascript es6.

The link is https://plus.google.com/u/0/+DimuDesigns/posts/9FDJx2qe4gZ

The example they give works fine for me in as a separate function.

```
function readData() {
  var id = '1P4aVeFJMT9e0ijoFt262IuLlnjHte8hl2iUeU_kk-AQ'; //ID of the 
projects spreadsheet
  var ass = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id); //Initilize spreadsheet
  var sheet = ass.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); //Get sheet instence

  var row1data = sheet.getRange('A1:F1').getValues();

  [a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1] = [row1data];  

  //DEBUG
  Logger.log(a1);
}
```

expected output to log should be the data in cell A1 which is the first item in the array.

actual output is the array itself.

I am a beginner in general so a clear explanation with well commented code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this modification? I think that there are 2 errors in your script.

1. When the values of "a1","b1","c1","d1","e1" and "f1" are put in the cells of "A1:F1", `row1data` retrieved by `var row1data = sheet.getRange('A1:F1').getValues()` is like `[["a1","b1","c1","d1","e1","f1"]]`. This is 2 dimensional array.
2. Variables of `a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1` of `[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1]` are required to be declared.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

From:

```
[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1] = [row1data];  

//DEBUG
Logger.log(a1);
```

To:

```
var a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1;
[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1] = row1data[0];

//DEBUG
Logger.log(a1);
```

#### Note:

- Also you can use `[[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1]] = row1data` instead of `[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1] = row1data[0]`.
- As a sample, if `[row1data]` in your script is used, it becomes `[[[a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1]]] = [row1data]`.

#### Reference:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())

Comment: Almost right. What I ultimately want is to unpack the array to individual variables.

Comment: @Yoel Vinitsky Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. If I misunderstood your question and  my answer was incomplete, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: OK It appears that your modification works but unpacks to a simple array. I did what you suggested and then initialized a second set of variables and repeated and it worked! thank you.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.